# Compositional Data Analysis: What is the connection between Soft-max Regression / Logistic Regression and Linear Regression in the Simplex Space?

Tags: regression, logistic, softmax, compositional-data

As someone just learning Compositional Data Analysis, my understanding is the following:

- The sample space for Compositional Data Analysis is the Simplex Space. Useful transformations like ALR/ILR/CLR transform the sample space to the Euclidean so that traditional statistical models can be employed (e.g. Linear Regression).
- Aitchinson demonstrated that Linear Regression in the Simplex Space (using Aitchinson Gemoetry) was equivalent to the LogRatio transforms.
- ALR is the same as softmax.

Therefore, given soft-max is the ALR transform, is Logistic Regression (or Soft-max Regression for the multivariate case) equivalent to Linear Regression in the Simplex Space?

If this is true, can anyone said some light on why ILR is not used given the mathematical benefits (e.g. Neural Network Classifiers, Logistic/Soft-max Regression)?

Comment: Great question. If you ever learned the answer, mind posting it as an answer below?

Comment: @grisaitis I am still none the wiser.